# increasing font size of ticks

Tags: matplotlib, font-size, xticks

i have a simple x,y plot that i want to increase the font of of ticks on x and y axes, so that they match the font size of x,y labels - fontsize=30. i also need to change the spacing on both axes so that they look more or less like the picture below, although the data sets are different.

thanks in advance.

[image: wished plot]

[image: my plot]

my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
x = [1.53,0.84,0.7,0.6,0.53,0.47,0.38,0.35]
y = [19.64,14.33,11.25,7.58,2.84,0.87,0.36,0]
plt.plot(x, y, marker="o")

plt.xlabel(r'Grid spacing $\AA$', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('% error', fontsize=20)
plt.title('Protein solvation', fontsize=20)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
```

[image]

---

You can also use these functions to set the tick positions and labels:

```
plt.xticks(x, map(lambda x: f'{x:.2f}', x), fontsize=20, rotation=90)
plt.yticks([0, 10, 20], ['0', '10', '20'], fontsize=20)
```

[image]
(plotted with `plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))`)

Comment: could you also help with the x-y axes tick spacings? @Stef

Comment: @sphero please see the updated answer.